# How do I sum the results of each loop done in VBA, Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Also how do I stop the loop from taking in empty cells? I've tried Do While and Do Until but it still takes in the empty cells. I want the code to take the values in the Input Values tab one row at a time and give results for each one until an empty cell. Then sum the results given by each row of inputs. This is the code I have so far. The calculation itself works, but the loop doesn't.

'''

```
Sub TEST()

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 1000000
i = i + 1

'Pasting Input Values into Inputs Taken
Sheets("Input Values").Range("A" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("B" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("C" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("D" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("E" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("C11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("F" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("G" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("C16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("H" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("D16").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("I" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("J" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G10").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("K" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G11").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("L" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("M" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G13").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Input Values").Range("N" & i).Copy
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G14").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Setting Opening PUP to 100% and refreshing
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G5").Value = 1
Application.CalculateFull

'Calculating No RPs
Sheets("Output").Range("C7").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!BJ6:BJ365,Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C8").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BK6:BK365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C10").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BM6:BM365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C11").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BN6:BN365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C12").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BO6:BO365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C13").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BP6:BP365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C14").Formula = "=SUM(Output!C11:C13)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C17").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BS6:BS365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C18").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BT6:BT365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C19").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BU6:BU365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C20").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BV6:BV365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C21").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BW6:BW365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C22").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BX6:BX365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C23").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BY6:BY365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C24").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BZ6:BZ365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C25").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!CA6:CA365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C26").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!CB6:CB365)"

Sheets("Output").Range("C5").Formula = "=Model!BL6-Model!BS6-Model!BT6"
Sheets("Output").Range("C15").Formula = "=SUM(Output!C7:C10,Output!C14)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C27").Formula = "=SUM(Output!C17:C26)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C29").Formula = "=-SUM(Model!AN6:AN365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C30").Formula = "=-SUM(Model!AP6:AP365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("C31").Formula = "=-Output!C2"
Sheets("Output").Range("C33").Formula = "=SUM(Output!C29:C31,Output!C27,Output!C15)"

'Removing Formulas from output
Sheets("Output").Range("C5:C33").Copy
Sheets("Output").Range("C5:C33").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Changing PUP rate
Sheets("Inputs Taken").Range("G5").Value = 0
Application.CalculateFull

'Calculate with RP
Sheets("Output").Range("D7").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!BJ6:BJ365,Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D8").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BK6:BK365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D10").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BM6:BM365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D11").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BN6:BN365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D12").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BO6:BO365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D13").Formula = _
        "=SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BP6:BP365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D14").Formula = "=SUM(Output!D11:D13)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D17").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BS6:BS365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D18").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BT6:BT365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D19").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BU6:BU365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D20").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BV6:BV365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D21").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BW6:BW365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D22").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BX6:BX365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D23").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BY6:BY365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D24").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!BZ6:BZ365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D25").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!CA6:CA365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D26").Formula = _
        "=-SUMPRODUCT(Model!AD6:AD365,Model!AG6:AG365,Model!CB6:CB365)"

Sheets("Output").Range("D5").Formula = "=Model!BL6-Model!BS6-Model!BT6"
Sheets("Output").Range("D15").Formula = "=SUM(Output!D7:D10,Output!D14)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D27").Formula = "=SUM(Output!D17:D26)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D29").Formula = "=-SUM(Model!AN6:AN365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D30").Formula = "=-SUM(Model!AP6:AP365)"
Sheets("Output").Range("D31").Formula = "=-Output!C2"
Sheets("Output").Range("D33").Formula = "=SUM(Output!D29:D31,Output!D27,Output!D15)"

'Removing Formulas from output
Sheets("Output").Range("D5:D33").Copy
Sheets("Output").Range("D5:D33").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


If Sheets("Input Values").Cells(i, 2).Value = "" Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Try researching a little more @shud. You already have you answer in your code. The variable i in your for loop is increased by 1 every time the loop runs. You need to use a similar approach.

Answer (score 0):

As is the case with all heroic efforts undertaken against all odds, your attempt at coding is truly inspiring. I have reduced your code but not quite enough. As you perhaps see, the middle section is repeated twice, once for column C and then for column D, and that should have been achieved by calling the same procedure twice, with just one different argument. Perhaps you will make this your task over the Easter holidays :-) Here's your revised code.

```
Sub TEST()

    Dim WsIn As Worksheet               ' Input
    Dim WsT As Worksheet                ' Taken
    Dim WsOut As Worksheet              ' Output
    Dim WsMod As Worksheet              ' Model
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim Rl As Long
    Dim R As Long
    Dim Rout As Long                    ' WsOut row
    Dim Cmod As Long                    ' WsMod column


    Set WsT = Sheets("Inputs Taken")
    Set WsIn = Sheets("Input Values")
    Set WsOut = Sheets("Output")
    Set WsMod = Sheets("Model")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Rl = WsIn.Cells(WsIn.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For R = 1 To Rl
        'Pasting Input Values into Inputs Taken
        With WsIn
            Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 1), .Cells(R, 4)).Value
            WsT.Cells(5, "D").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                             .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
            Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 5), .Cells(R, 6)).Value
            WsT.Cells(11, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
            Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 7), .Cells(R, 8)).Value
            WsT.Cells(16, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr
            Arr = .Range(.Cells(R, 9), .Cells(R, 14)).Value
            WsT.Cells(9, "G").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)) _
                             .Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
        End With

        'Setting Opening PUP to 100% and refreshing
        WsT.Cells(5, "G").Value = 1

        'Calculating No RPs
        With WsOut
            Cmod = 62                       ' BJ:BP
            For Rout = 7 To 13
                If Rout <> 9 Then           ' skip result in C9
                    .Cells(Rout, "C").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod)
                    Cmod = Cmod + 1
                End If
            Next Rout
            .Cells(14, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C11:C13"))

            Cmod = 71                       ' BS:CB
            For Rout = 17 To 26
                .Cells(Rout, "C").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsMod, True)
                Cmod = Cmod + 1
            Next Rout
            .Cells(5, 3).Value = WsMod.Cells(6, "BL").Value _
                               - WsMod.Cells(6, "BS").Value _
                               - WsMod.Cells(6, "BT").Value
            .Cells(15, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C7:C10, C14"))
            .Cells(27, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C17:C26"))
            .Cells(29, 3).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AN6:AN365")) * -1
            .Cells(30, 3).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AP6:AP365")) * -1
            .Cells(31, 3).Value = WsOut.Cells(2, 3).Value * -1
            .Cells(33, 3).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("C29:C31, C15, C27"))
        End With

        'Changing PUP rate
        WsT.Cells(5, "G").Value = 0             ' Excel should recalculate automatically
'        Application.CalculateFull

        'Calculate with RP
        With WsOut
            Cmod = 62                       ' BJ:BP
            For Rout = 7 To 13
                If Rout <> 9 Then           ' skip result in D9
                    .Cells(Rout, "D").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsOut)
                    Cmod = Cmod + 1
                End If
            Next Rout
            .Cells(14, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D11:D13"))

            Cmod = 71                       ' BS:CB
            For Rout = 17 To 26
                .Cells(Rout, "D").Value = SumProduct(Cmod, WsOut, True)
                Cmod = Cmod + 1
            Next Rout
            .Cells(5, 4).Value = WsMod.Cells(6, "BL").Value _
                               - WsMod.Cells(6, "BS").Value _
                               - WsMod.Cells(6, "BT").Value
            .Cells(15, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D7:D10, D14"))
            .Cells(27, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D17:D26"))
            .Cells(29, 4).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AN6:AN365")) * -1
            .Cells(30, 4).Value = Application.Sum(WsMod.Range("AP6:AP365")) * -1
            .Cells(31, 4).Value = WsOut.Cells(2, 3).Value * -1
            .Cells(33, 4).Value = Application.Sum(.Range("D29:D31, D15, D27"))
        End With

Exit For
    Next R
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function SumProduct(ByVal Cmod As Long, _
                            WsMod As Worksheet, _
                            Optional ByVal Negative As Boolean) As Double
    Dim AuxRng As Range

    With WsMod
        Set AuxRng = .Range(.Cells(6, Cmod), .Cells(365, Cmod))
        SumProduct = Application.SumProduct( _
                    .Range("AD6:AD365"), _
                    .Range("AG6:AG365"), _
                     AuxRng) * IIf(Negative, -1, 1)
    End With
End Function
```

I draw your attention to the end of the main procedure where it says `Exit For`. This curtails the run to a single loop. I thought, perhaps you never saw the result of your labors. In some instances you are converting columns to rows, and to save my life I wouldn't be able to tell where to put the next line of your data, not to mention the 999,998 you were hoping for. I have reduced that number to the actual number of rows in your worksheet but that isn't the problem. The immediate problem is where to put the next data set - or how that data set could be different from the one the code now generates.

Comment: Thanks for this. The calculation is giving all 0 values in the output and I can't see why. Do you know why? When I merged our code it fixed this but I don't think that would be the best way. Also what do you mean by 'where to put the next data set'? Are you talking about the output? If so I want the sum of all the outputs to be in wsOut.

Comment: I presume the `SumProduct` function returns zero. I suggest you test it the way I did. Create a sheet with a few small ranges filled with numbers that let you see what the function calculates, create a test sub with something like `Debug.Print SumProduct(7, ActiveSheet, True)` and step through the procedure with F8 while looking at the Locals window. Bear in mind that Excel's SUMPRODUCT function, used here, must return 0 if any of the factors = 0. I suspect that the `AuxRng` might not work as I visualized. I just took it for granted and never tested it.

Comment: `WsT.Cells(5, "D").Resize(UBound(Arr, 2), UBound(Arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)` writes to D5:D8 (I believe). But `WsT.Cells(11, "C").Resize(UBound(Arr), UBound(Arr, 2)).Value = Arr` writes to C11:D11. Your present code would write to the same cells on each loop but presuming this isn't the target, the existing destinations can't just be offset by 1 without ending up overlapping the previous loop's result. But I suggest we leave that subject to another thread. There's no space here. Let's just get the first loop to work for now.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. You had WsOut instead of WsMod in the SumProduct formula. That change made it work as intended. I actually do want to overwrite the same cells in each loop but have the sum of the loops in the cells instead of the results of just the last loop.e.g say C11 in WsOut gives 5 on the 1st loop and 7 on the 2nd loop. The value I want in C11 is 12 at the end. Is this possible?

Comment: Thank you for finding that error. I have modified the above code in two instances accordingly. The principal method for aggregating results is like `Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value + 10` or, if you have variables called *MyTotal* and *Addition* then `MyTotal = MyTotal + Addition`. If you can't find the place in the existing code where this can be implemented please ask a new question about that.

Comment: I understand what you mean but I can't figure out how to add the range. I tried 'Set OutputC =  WsOut.range("C5:C33")' and then OutputC = OutputC+OutputC but that gave an error probably because I put 'Dim OutputC as Range'. Would I have to assign all the cells individually and then put 'Cells(1, 1).Value = Cells(1, 1).Value + Cells(1, 1).Value '?

Comment: I don't think it's that easy. But you are a persistent guy and if you chew on it for a few days you'll probably find the way. If you can't make it the subject of another question. There is no room here to expand.